# How to parse XML in python using ElementTree (find content of a tag)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to write a python script to find the content of an XML tag and print back to me for any lines it finds.

So far I have
__

```
import os
import sys

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for fn in os.listdir(".") :
    if fn.endswith(".xml") :
        if not os.path.exists(fn) :
            sys.exit(fn+' does not exist')
        doc = ET.parse(fn)
**      for e in doc.findall( ".//ChangeView/VideoPlaying/text() = 'true'" ) :
            print(fn+' has '+ET.tostring(e))
```

for a XML document that has

```
<ChangeView>
    <VideoPlaying>true</VideoPlaying>
</ChangeView>
```

The main problem is the line with the **, what is the syntax to detect the content of the VideoPlaying tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for e in doc.findall('.//ChangeView/VideoPlaying'):
    if e.text == 'true':
        print(ET.tostring(e))
```